# actionscript 3 two class two stage one movieclip

Tags: class, actionscript-3

I have 1 classA in stage1 and 1 classB in stage2.
On stage1 there is a movieclip instance name MC. 
On stage2 there is a movieclip instance name MC (same instance name as stage1).

classA:

```
package {

    public class classA extends MovieClip {

    public function classA(): void {

        }
        public function prenditutti(obj: MovieClip): void{
            //mc is movieclip in stage1 and work correctly
            MC.addChild(obj);
       }
    }
}
```

classB: (I use it in stage2 and there is a movieclip instance, like in stage1, named mc)

```
package {

    import livingroom;

    public class classB extends MovieClip {
        //calamita_inventario is a movieclip linkage in library
        public var calamita_inv_cost: calamita_inventario = new calamita_inventario(); 

        public var LR: classA = new classA();

        public function classB() {
            // constructor code
        }

        public function prendicalamita(e: MouseEvent) {
            LR.prenditutti(calamita_inv_cost);
            //I should see in stage2 inside a MC my movieclip calamita_inv_cost, but doesn't work.
        }
    }
}
```

But in stage2 i can't see addChild.
need help

Comment: What do you mean you can't "see" `addChild` ?

Comment: What exactly are stage1 and stage2? How did you create those?

Comment: The `addChild()` method **is** accessible inside your `classB` and through its `LR` field! How do you use the `classB` on your "stage"?! Have you added an instance of it on your stage?! Most probably, we cannot provide an answer just through guessing; so, clarify your problem :)

Comment: ClassB is a linkage assign to movieclip in stage. stage1 and stage2 are two scenes in flash. Funcion prenditutti are called correctly in classB, but in scene2 doesn't work addChild, I don't see nothing (maybe becouse MC is also in scene1)